# BitSet Printing in C

Tags: c

So, here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/MejYmpvK

I'm trying to get the output to display this:

```
The BitSet is:
0000000001001010

Modified BitSet at index '14' = '1' is:
0010000001001010

The value at index '14' is:
1

Modified Bitset at index '14' = '0' is:
0000000001001010

The value at index '14' is:
0
```

However, it is giving me this output instead:

```
The BitSet is:
0000000001001010

Modified BitSet at index '14' = '1' is:
0010000001001010

The value at index '14' is:
0

Modified Bitset at index '14' = '0' is:
0000000001001010

The value at index '14' is:
0
```

Everything is working perfectly except for the display method. Not sure what is going on here (the whole code is in the pastebin link above):

```
/* Returns the value of the bit at 'index' */
int bitValue(bitSet bs, int index){

    /* Shifts right to the passed index value */
    int value = ((bs & (int)pow(power, index)) >> index);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It seems what you expect to be at index 14 is actually at index 13 (the indexing starts from 0). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: You forgot to update `value` after setting bit 14, so of course it printed the old value.  You need to call `bitValue` again to get the new value.  Your local variable `value` won't magically change all by itself, right?

Comment: Thanks guys for the useful information! Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main function isn't updating the value after you set the bit.  Try this;

```
int main () {
    bitSet bits = makeBitSet();
    int value = bitValue(bits, 14);

    printf("The BitSet is: \n");
    displayBitSet(bits);
    printf("\n\nModified BitSet at index '14' = '1' is: \n");
    setBit(&bits, 14);
    displayBitSet(bits);
    printf("\n\nThe value at index '14' is: \n");
    value = bitValue(bits, 14);
    printf("%d", value);
    printf("\n\nModified BitSet at index '14' = '0' is: \n");
    clearBit(&bits, 14);
    displayBitSet(bits);
    printf("\n\nThe value at index '14' is: \n");
    value = bitValue(bits, 14);
    printf("%d\n", value);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even realize that. What a small stupid mistake.